# how to optimize this script...?

Tags: javascript, optimization

can anyone plz tell me how to optimize this JS..
trying to do but facing too much problem..

```
$('.sub-about, #overabout').mouseenter(function(e) {
  $('#overabout').addClass('slide');
});
$('.sub-about, #overabout').mouseleave(function(e){
  $('#overabout').removeClass('slide');
});
$('.sub-education, #overeducation').mouseenter(function(e) {
  $('#overeducation').addClass('slide');
});
$('.sub-education, #overeducation').mouseleave(function(e){
  $('#overeducation').removeClass('slide');
});
```

Comment: Seems optimized just fine, but there are more readable ways to write it.

Comment: please provide your html too - are there multiple sub-about elements? and should they all target the overabout element?  same with the overreducation

Comment: i was just trying to on hover hide n show div and this is working. i need only optimization..

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, if you can't provide the minimum html we can't really see if we can optimise the script as we don't know whether it is effecting the right elements.  For example you may be able to add a class to all the elements and use a data attribute to combine those functions together.  Also this question may be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean less code with "optimize" then have a look at this:

```
$('.sub-about, #overabout').hover(function(e) {
    $(this)[e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('slide');
});
$('.sub-education, #overeducation').hover(function(e) {
    $(this)[e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('slide');
});
```

the selectors could also be merged. so even shorter would be:

```
$('#overabout, #overeducation, .sub-education, .sub-about').hover(function(e) {
    $(this)[e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('slide');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aywgvoh7/

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to do here without seeing the rest of the HTML/CSS as others have said. One thing I do tend to do though, is store the jQuery selections in variables (if your html isn't going to change) so that you're not searching the DOM for them everytime.

```
$overeducation = $('#overeducation');
$overabout     = $('#overabout');

$('.sub-about, #overabout').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $overabout.addClass('slide');
});
$('.sub-about, #overabout').mouseleave(function(e){
    $overabout.removeClass('slide');
});
$('.sub-education, #overeducation').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $overeducation.addClass('slide');
});
$('.sub-education, #overeducation').mouseleave(function(e){
    $overeducation.removeClass('slide');
});
```

It's a minor improvement though, but that's basically all you can do in this instance. You'd only see a real improvement in performance if you have a LOT of elements with the classed `.sub-about` and `.sub-education`.